# Fix/stick image to top after scrolling - the image jumps to the top straight away?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have an image in the center of my webpage. Once the user scrolls and the image hits the top of the window, I am attempting to fix the image to the top of the page so that it scrolls with the page.

However, instead of it sticking when it hits the top of the window, the image is currently jumping to the top of the page as soon as the user scrolls. Although I would like the image to stay fixed at the top while the user is on the page, it stays fixed when the page is refreshed!

Can't seem to figure this out - please help!

**index.html**

```
<img src="./assets/img/logo.png" class="logo" alt="Logo">
```

**style.css**

```
.logo {
   width: 500px;
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 200px;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   margin: auto;
}
```

**main.js**

```
$(function() {
  var boxInitialTop = $('.logo').offset().top;
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > boxInitialTop) {
      $('.logo').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
    } else {
      $('.logo').css({position: 'absolute'});
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think all you need to do is reset the initial top value when you scroll back down:

```js
  var boxInitialTop = $('.logo').offset().top;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > boxInitialTop) {
      $('.logo').css({
        position: 'fixed',
        top: '0px'
      });
    } else {
      $('.logo').css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: '200px'         // add this to "reset" the top to it's original (that you set in your css)
      });
    }
  });
```

```css
body {height:2000px;}

#test {
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.logo {
  width: 500px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/city/" class="logo" alt="Logo">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Pete - thanks for responding! The image still jumps from the center to the top instantly as soon as the user scrolls - I am attempting to get it to fix to the top only when the user scrolls and the image hits the top of the window.

Also, I would like the image to stay fixed at the top, only returning to its original position when the page is refreshed.

Any Thoughts?

Comment: @domburford, what browser are you using as it seems to do what you say it should for me (I am using latest version of chrome) - if you use the full page link for the snippet and start scrolling down, the image doesn't stick at the top until you get to the top of it?

Comment: Apologies! It works if I remove this fade & transition from my code https://jsfiddle.net/uot0un4y/ - don't know why this is effecting the scroll & fix  solution..

Comment: @domburford ah ok, if your window and logo starts off as display:none; then your offset top will be 0, which is why the logo will jump to the top straight away.  You will need to calculate the offset once your fadeIn have finished - set a global var in the callback function of your fadeIn - something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/uot0un4y/1/

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I couldn't get that to work so might just set boxInitialTop manually e.g. `if ($(window).scrollTop() > 205`. The page refresh is still causing an issue :/ - the image remains fixed at the top..

Comment: Is the page refresh done with js? Can you set up a fiddle that replicates the error?

Answer (score 2):

your code works.

you only have to reset the `top` value in the `else` section.
This way it stays `0px` because it was set this way in the `if` section.

Comment: Hi - thanks for your response! The code works, but the image jumps from the center to the top instantly as soon as the user scrolls. I am attempting to get it to fix to the top only when the user scrolls and the image hits the top of the window.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the original placement of the element back to where it started (after the else). Once the element returns to `position:absolute` you need to ensure that it's `top` property is returned back to `200px` otherwise it will still hold the value that was set when it was `fixed` i.e. `0`.

See below:

```js
$(function() {
  var boxInitialTop = $('.logo').offset().top;
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > boxInitialTop) {
      $('.logo').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
    } else {
      $('.logo').css({position: 'absolute', top : boxInitialTop+'px'});
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi - thank you for your feedback! The issue is the image jumps & sticks to the top as soon as the user begins to scroll - moving from the center straight to the top instantly.

Comment: That's very strange. Perhaps try to replicate it in a jsfiddle and post it here so we can work from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ( function ()  { 
  var boxInitialTop = $ ( '.logo' ). offset (). top ; 
  $ ( window ). scroll ( function  ()  { 
    if  ( $ ( window ). scrollTop ()  > boxInitialTop )  { 
      $ ( '.logo' ). css ({ position :  'relative' , top :  '0px' }); 
    }  else  { 
      $ ( '.logo' ). css ({ position :  'absolute' }); 
    } 
  }); 
});
```